# Disable ListView Scroll

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

Is possible to disable ListView Scroll if page don't overflow the screen size?

I always use ListView to avoid overflow the screen, but when the content of the page is smaller than screen I can see the end scroll animation, how can i disable the scroll in this cases, and able to scroll if the screen size is small??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to use a [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html):

> This widget is useful when you have a single box that will normally be
>   entirely visible, for example a clock face in a time picker, but you
>   need to make sure it can be scrolled if the container gets too small
>   in one axis (the scroll direction).

And instead of using a `ListView` just use a `Column` and place it inside of the `SingleChildScrollView`:

```dart
    SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[/**/],
        ),
    )
```

Or if you need to use `ListView` for some reason, you can use `shrinkWrap` with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`:

```dart
    SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[/**/],
        ),
    )
```

Comment: Perfect, the singleChildScrollView works exactly like i want.

Comment: I like the `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` option best to diasable scolling. Also works perfectly with `ListWheelScrollView`

Answer (score 12):

You can set the scroll physics property on the ListView, which will disable scrolling:

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

You can also switch between enabling or disabling scrolling at runtime if you have to via some condition like so:

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: disableScrolling ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() : 
         AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Answer (score 8):

Unless that scroll view needs to use the parent's `PrimaryScrollController`, setting the `ListView`'s `primary` property to `false` will result in the scroll view scrolling only if there is enough content.

`property` documentation:

> Whether this is the primary scroll view associated with the parent
>   PrimaryScrollController.
>
> When this is true, the scroll view is scrollable even if it does not
>   have sufficient content to actually scroll. Otherwise, by default the
>   user can only scroll the view if it has sufficient content. See
>   physics.
>
> On iOS, this also identifies the scroll view that will scroll to top
>   in response to a tap in the status bar.
>
> Defaults to true when scrollDirection is Axis.vertical and controller
>   is null.