# Flutter - Disabling scroll while interacting with the chart

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

I have a dashboard containing

```
ListView
  - fl_chart
  - Column: List<ProductCard>
```

I would like to prevent user to scroll down the page while interacting with the chart.
How to do so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54018254/15106159

Comment: I found another way I just applied. From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246120/disable-listview-scroll

Answer (score 0):

go to Your scrollable widget and add

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```